# I kept getting TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, psql

I've been trying to run this code but kept getting a type error, I've searched the web but didn't find solution to my problem. 
N.B: This is a fraction of the whole code

```
@app.route("/search", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    if "user_email" not in session:
        return render_template("sign.html", error="Please Login First", work="Failed")

    if request.method == 'GET':
        title = request.form.get('title')
        isbn = request.form.get('isbn')
        author = request.form.get('author')     
        searchs = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author iLIKE '%"+author+"%' OR title iLIKE '%"+title+"%' OR isbn iLIKE '%"+isbn+"%'").fetchall()
        return render_template('search.html', work = 'Success', searchs = searchs )
```

Comment: `request.form.get` will return `None` if the key is not in the form.  So you need to handle the cases where "title", "isbn" or "author" are not in the form.  Your query assumes that they are all present.

Comment: @snakecharmerb how do I handle the case, I'm a beginner

Comment: Read the documentation, look up how to write conditionals and handle exceptions in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, a reasonably simple solution to the problem is to run separate queries for each variable, *if* they are provided, and merge them into a single list for the template (we can get away with this because we're always querying the same table, so the output rows will always have the same structure).

```
@app.route("/search", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    if "user_email" not in session:
        return render_template("sign.html", error="Please Login First", work="Failed")

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Make a list to hold the results.
        searches = []
        title = request.form.get('title')
        if title is not None:
            titles = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title ILIKE %s", ('%'+title+'%',)).fetchall()
            searchs.extend(titles)
        isbn = request.form.get('isbn')
        if isbn is not None:
            isbns = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn ILIKE %s", ('%'+isbn+'%',)).fetchall()
            searchs.extend(isbns)
        author = request.form.get('author')    
        if author is not None:
            authors = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author ILIKE %s", ('%'+author+'%',)).fetchall()
            searchs.extend(authors) 
        return render_template('search.html', work = 'Success', searchs = searchs )
```

There are better ways to do this, but this should work for now.  Note that the form of the queries

```
result = db.execute("SELECT thing FROM table WHERE thing = %s", (value,))
```

ensures that the query values are sent to the database in the format it expects (they are "quoted", in the jargon), and prevents SQL injection attacks, when a malicious user enters SQL scripts into your web form to see if they can download data from your database, or change or delete the data it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are getting this error because the request.form.get() is returning a None value. Also, request.form is used to retrieve POST Data but it seems like you are using this for a GET request.

In the past, I have used this command to get parameters from a GET request

```
search = request.args.get("search_query", "")
```

The 2nd parameter in request.args.get is a default value

the .fetchall() is not needed and may be the reason, You should use db.engine.execute()

```
query = ('SELECT State_name, count(State_name) FROM "University" group by State_name')

res = db.engine.execute(query)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But now the search is returning all data in my database

Comment: I added to the answer